# Atomicity of save() in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Let's consider a table in database:

```
Book:

+--------+
|id|title|
----------
```

The table is empty.

Now, I have a piece of code:

```
from django.db import models

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)


def f(title):
    b = Book()
    b.id = 1
    b.title = title
    b.save()
```

And, I have two processes:

Process 1 executes: `f('t1')`

Process 2 executes `f('t2')`

What if the following situation will take place?

The `save()` looks like ( based on what I read from documentation)

```
(1) UPDATE # if primary_key is set
(2) INSERT # if UPDATE returns 0 rows or primary_key = None
```

What if the second process executed (1) operation. Now, the first process executed (1) and (2) operation. And now, the second process tries to execute (2). ERROR.

So, in fact, the question is: It is safe when it comes to atomicity? Does django ensures atomicity in that situation? If not, how can I do it?

Please note that:
I know that I can make it to be a transaction. I am asking if I **have to do it.**

Comment: Why would you set the id manually? It's an auto incrementing field, you should let the db set it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I know it. The question was another.

Answer (score 3):

The documented `save()` logic that you summarized is run within a transaction in the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11/django/db/models/base.py#L833).

However, that transaction is not going to protect against the situation you describe. The default database isolation level probably doesn't apply, and the `save()` code doesn't have any mechanism to retry the update if the insert raises an `IntegrityError`.

Now, Django *does* have a solution to this problem, and it's [`update_or_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create), which, along with `get_or_create()`, "is atomic assuming correct usage, correct database configuration, and correct behavior of the underlying database". See the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11/django/db/models/query.py#L467) to understand how it achieves this.

So your best bet is probably to use that, something like:

```
def f(title):
    Book.objects.update_or_create(
        id=1, 
        defaults={"title": title},
    )
```

Comment: "However, that transaction is not going to protect against the situation you describe.". Why?

Comment: @Gilgamesz: It says it's "prone to a race-condition... if uniqueness is not enforced at the database level". Since the uniqueness of `id` *is* enforced at the database level, that doesn't apply to the situation you described. As to your second question, the rest of that paragraph is describing why. Let me know if you have a more specific question.

Comment: thanks- you right.  My question was not specific. The question is:
I don't understand why uniqueness ensures that it is race condition safe. Otherwise, it is not.

Comment: After all, in `update_or_create` there is `transaction.atomic(using=self.db):`. So I don't understand why uniqueness matters- it has been taken lock for a database ( or table)

Comment: @Gilgamesz: You might have a misunderstanding of what transactions are in the SQL world. They're not locks, and they're not what you might think of as "atomic" in other contexts. The specific behavior is complicated and depends on the *transaction isolation level* and its database-specific implementation (see [PostgreSQL's docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html), for example).

Comment: @Gilgamesz: In your specific scenario, uniqueness matters because it causes the database to reject the second `INSERT` with an error. `update_or_create()` detects that error and does an `UPDATE` instead. Look through the code I linked to to fully understand the algorithm.

Comment: you right that I misunderstanding transactions. You said that I cannot think about it as atomicity from other worlds. But, when I read in documentation about `@transaction.atomic` it is said that:  
"atomic allows us to create a block of code within which the atomicity on the database is guaranteed". Now, I am confused.

Comment: @Gilgamesz: They are atomic in the SQL sense ("on the database"), I'm just pointing out that these terms - *transaction*, *atomic*, *isolation* - all have specific meanings and implications. Coming from another context where the terms are used differently you might end up with a misunderstanding (for example, thinking that transactions are like locks).

Comment: " They are atomic in the SQL sense ("on the database"), ", what does it mean? Is it dependant of isolation level? How?